# How to get the selected equipment object id

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

we have used forge Aggregate Viewer to display the multiple BIM models. But if we click/double click any of the equipment in the Aggregate Forge Viewer the equipment will be zoomed.
but not able to get the selected equipment object id by using the c# code.
Note: If we upload the single file, we are able to get the selected equipment object id in the Forge Viewer.

We used below code, but its not get hitted when we select equipment.
 `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {`

Kindly help us to get the selected equipment object id in Aggregate Forge View while displaying the multiple files.
Kindly share the sample code for our reference.

**FITTOVIEW AND SELECTION CHANGE CODE**

```
const Loadedevent = () => {
        var objval = document.getElementById('<%=hid_objectid.ClientID%>').value;
        if (objval != '') {
                   var mdlurn = "";
                    mdlurn = document.getElementById('<%=hid_mdlurn.ClientID%>').value;
            const models = viewer.getVisibleModels().find(m => m.getData().urn === mdlurn);
                viewer.fitToView([parseInt(objval)], models);
                viewer.select([parseInt(objval)], models, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);
        }
    }
```

**SelectionChangeEvent**

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {                       
       if (args.dbIdArray.length === 1) {
                             viewer.getProperties(args.dbIdArray[0], function (data) {
                                 if (FromPage == '') {
                                     if (FromSelection == '') {
                                         if (Count === 0) {                                            
                                             var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
                                             var parentId = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(args.dbIdArray[0]);                                             
                                             viewer.select([parentId], viewer.model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);
                                             Count = 1;
                                         } else {                                             
                                             itemobject = args.dbIdArray[0];
                                             Count = 0;
                                         }
                                     } else {                                         
                                         FromSelection = '';
                                         itemobject = args.dbIdArray[0];
                                     }
                                 } else {
                                     FromPage = '';                                     
                                    itemobject = args.dbIdArray[0];
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                     });
```

**Edited Code:**

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {  
                      if (!args.selections || args.selections.length <= 0)                          
                          return;

                      if (args.selections.length == 1 ) {                     
                          viewer.getProperties(args.selections[0].dbIdArray[0], function (data) {
                                 if (FromPage == '') {
                                     if (FromSelection == '') {
                                         if (Count === 0) {
                                             
                                             var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;                                            
                                             var parentId = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(args.selections[0].dbIdArray);                                            
                                             viewer.select([parentId], viewer.model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);
                                             Count = 1;
                                         } else {                                            
                                             const dbIds = args.selections[0].dbIdArray;                                             
                                             itemobject = dbIds[0];                                             
                                             Count = 0;                                             
                                         }
                                     } else {
                                        
                                         FromSelection = '';                                  
                                         const dbIds = args.selections[0].dbIdArray;
                                             itemobject = dbIds[0];
                                      
                                     }
                                 } else {
                                     FromPage = '';
                                     const dbIds = args.selections[0].dbIdArray;
                                             itemobject = dbIds[0];   
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the multiple models scenario, you must use `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` instead. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

```js
/**
 * Triggered when objects are selected or deselected.
 * Event payload:
 * {
 *   type: 'aggregateSelection',
 *   target: Viewer3D,
 *   selections: Array<{
 *     model: Model,
 *     nodeArray: Array<number>,
 *     dbIdArray: Array<number>,
 *     fragIdsArray: Array<number>
 *   }>
 * }
 */
viewer.addEventListener(
   Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
   (event) => {
        // codes for selecting changed
   });
```

To get selected objects, call `viewer.getAggregateSelection()` instead.

## Update

Here are the revised code snippets for you:

### FITTOVIEW AND SELECTION CHANGE CODE

```js
const Loadedevent = () => {
    let objval = document.getElementById('<%=hid_objectid.ClientID%>').value;
    if (objval != '') {
        let mdlurn = "";
        mdlurn = document.getElementById('<%=hid_mdlurn.ClientID%>').value;
        let model = viewer.getVisibleModels().find(m => m.getData().urn === mdlurn); //!<<< find() will return first found item only, so defining the variable in the singular form instead to avoid confusion.

        let dbId = parseInt( objval );
        viewer.select( [ dbId ] , model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED );
        // or viewer.setAggregateSelection([ { ids: [ dbId ], model, selectionType: Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED } ]);

        viewer.fitToView( [ dbId ], model );
    }
}
```

### SelectionChangeEvent

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (event) => {
    if (!event.selections || event.selections.length <= 0 || event.selections.length > 1)
        return;

    let selSet = event.selections[0];
    const dbIds = selSet.dbIdArray;
    const model = selSet.model;
    const dbId = dbIds[0];

    model.getProperties(dbId, function(data) {
        if (FromPage == '') {
            if (FromSelection == '') {
                if (Count === 0) {
                    let instanceTree = model.getInstanceTree();
                    let parentId = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(dbId);
                    viewer.select(parentId, model, Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED);
                    // or viewer.setAggregateSelection([ { ids: [parentId ], model, selectionType: Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType.OVERLAYED } ])
                    Count = 1;
                } else {
                    itemobject = dbId;
                    Count = 0;
                }
            } else {
                FromSelection = '';
                itemobject = dbId;
            }
        } else {
            FromPage = '';
            itemobject = dbId;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , I tried above Code `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {` it causes issue in `viewer.fitToView` getting error as **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')** Please refer Code in my edited Post.

Comment: Hi, please check my event payload above. the field you're referring to is in the selections array ... see https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/2bc0244cbf13f1c6357ea6d09d4d360313573c9f/bim360assets/wwwroot/js/BIM360AssetExtension.js#L842

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried the code, which u give in git hub.. Now getting objectId , but the issue is i'm getting all object ID in viewer.addEventListener. But we need the Object id of the selected asset in the Forge Viewer. Kindly help us on this. I have pasted the Edited code for your reference.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate? The Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT event will only give you selected object ids, not all ids. You may need to call the corresponding functions when passing `db Ids ` to the viewer.  See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher, some of them require the model object.

Comment: Kindly check the above edited code. As suggested we have used the below code ```   const dbIds = args.selections[0].dbIdArray;                                             
                                             itemobject = dbIds[0]; ``` to find out the selected equipment object id. But if we use the above code we are having multiple args like arg1,arg2,arg3 .....etc..Under each arguments we have received different objectid in the Array(1). So that not able to get the proper objectid.

Comment: You cannot use `viewer.model`. It always points to the first-loaded model. Instead, Please call `args.selections[i].model.getProperties( )` instad. If you searched my sample mentioned above, you could see similar implementations. See also at the bottom of this blog: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Comment: I modified your code snippets and shared them above.

Comment: Thank you @Eason kang. The above code is working fine. we are able to get the proper object id if we do the single click in Forge Viewer. But if we do double click on any equipment in Forge Viewer it is getting their parent object id instead of the selected equipment object id. Kindly help us on this.

Comment: Double-click won't change the selected target with my tests. Could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible test case with us `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` for investigation?

Comment: A non-confidential reproducible test case contains:
1. Non-confidential reproducible models 2. A runnable, minimum completed yet viewer app like the [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/) one would be fine. 3. Some instructions to reproduce the problem, like which object to select, where to click